# nodejs communication with multiple child processes, can't identify them

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tried to create multiple child processes from parent and communicate with them. But I have a hard time identifying the child process that generates an event. In the following, I am surprised to see the messages are only from child 1, I had hoped both child 0 and child 1 will send the message.

This nodejs (v8.4.0) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any idea why?

```
$ node te1.js 
got msg from child: 1 {"foo":"bar"}
got msg from child: 1 {"foo":"bar"}
hi you|
hi you|
CHILD got message: {"msg":"hi you"} |
CHILD got message: {"msg":"hi you"} |
```

=====te1.js==================

```
const cp = require('child_process');
var bats = [];
bats.push(cp.fork(`${__dirname}/te2.js`));
bats.push(cp.fork(`${__dirname}/te2.js`));

for (i=0; i<bats.length; i++) {
    bats[i]._id = i;
    var bat = bats[i]
    bat.on('message', function(resp) {
        console.log("got msg from child: " + bat._id + " " + JSON.stringify(resp));
    })

    bat.on('exit', function(code) {
        console.log("child " + bat._id + " proc exited")
    })

    bat.send({msg: "hi you"});
}
```

=======te2.js===================

```
process.on('message', (m) => {
    console.log(m.msg + "|")
  console.log('CHILD got message:', JSON.stringify(m), "|");
    if (m.msg == "exit") {
        console.log("exiting...")
        process.exit()
    }
});

process.send({ foo: 'bar' });
```

**UPDATE1**

Instrumented te2.js so it has `console.log(m.msg + "|" + process.pid)`,
This help me to confirm that both of the child processes actually received the message from parent process.

**UPDATE2**

In the message(s) that child sent to parent, it could add a pid field, i.e. change the last line in te2.js to `process.send({ foo: 'bar', pid: process.pid });`, I can check which child process sends the message.

However, it's unclear how to detect which child process exits.  Any ideas?

Comment: Magic trick: use `for (let i=0; i<bats.length; i++) { ... }`

Comment: @robertklep, tried it but got the same problem.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that `var bat = bats[i]` should be `let bat = bats[i]` as well.

Comment: Hi @robertklep your tip is wonderful! Could you write it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that variables declared using `var` are *not* scoped to the `for` block, which means that they "share" the same instance of the `i` variable in the loop. That's why it looks like the messages are being received from the same child.

Using `let` creates a proper block scope to fix that issue:

```
for (let i=0; i<bats.length; i++) { // <-- here
    bats[i]._id = i;
    let bat = bats[i]               // <-- and also here
    bat.on('message', function(resp) {
        console.log("got msg from child: " + bat._id + " " + JSON.stringify(resp));
    })

    bat.on('exit', function(code) {
        console.log("child " + bat._id + " proc exited")
    })

    bat.send({msg: "hi you"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your first process actually sent the `foo` message before the handler was added.  Maybe try adding a delay before sending the `foo` message.